# How to connect LYNC with CRM 2011 online?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-online

Am using MS Dynamics online CRM2011.I need to integrate the **lync with this CRM**.How to do this?how to make a **call for Lead through crm 2011 using lync**.Is this possible?Is there any Solutions available for do this?

Comment: You can see [here](http://rc.crm.dynamics.com/rc/2011/en-us/online/5.1_OSDP/help/how_sr_skype_integration.htm) how choose Lync or Skype to call. But be careful because of this warning: "Microsoft Office Lync is currently unsupported for automatic outgoing phone call functionality in Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online." from this [support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2800946?wa=wsignin1.0).

Answer (score 1):

Install Office Lync(Office Communications Server) in the User System and Go MS CRM Dynamics =>Select Setting=> Choose Administrator Option => Select System Setting and follows below :
[image]